# Limit in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $\lim\sqrt[n]{a}=1$(where $a > 0$ is a real number).

I know also that $\lim{\frac{1}{n}}=0$.

But, can you explain me why $\lim\sqrt[n]{2 + \frac{1}{n}}= 1$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $2<2+\frac1n\le 3$, yuo can compare your sequence with $\sqrt[n]2$ and $\sqrt[n]3$.

Answer (score 8):

Note that $\sqrt[n]{2+\frac{1}{n}}$ is **Squeezed** betweeen $1$ and $\sqrt[n]{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

More brute and straightforward: take log of the function, use L'Hospital's rule:
$$
\frac{\log (2+\frac{1}{x})}{x} \to-\frac{1}{x(x+2)}
$$
This limit tends to 0 as $x \to \infty$. Now if you exponentiate you get $e^0=1$